# Tmux: unknown option: c0-change-interval

Tags: tmux

I have compiled `tmux 1.9a` and added the following to my `tmux.conf` file:

```
setw -g c0-change-interval 50                                                      
setw -g c0-change-trigger 75
```

However, this doesn't seem to work (I get some messages at startup that say they're unknown options). When I type `setw -g c0-change-trigger 75` into tmux directly, I get:

```
unknown option: c0-change-interval
```

when I run `tmux -V` I get `tmux 1.9a`. My thinking is that the alias for the tmux `PATH` is set *after* I load tmux, and I'm actually running `tmux 1.6`, but I'm not aware of any way of checking what version of tmux is actually running.

When I run `ps -u` under `COMMAND` it just says `tmux -2 new`. Here is the relevant contents of my `.bashrc` file:

```
# this is where the compiled version of tmux 1.9a is:
export PATH="/home/quant/bin:$PATH"

# tmux                                                                          
# If not running interactively, do not do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

What is going on? As far as I know the c0-change-interval command is supported by tmux 1.9a, and this is what I *seem* to be running.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the original poster's problem but if anyone is coming up on this now the problem is actually that c0-change-interval and c0-change-trigger have been removed completely.

From: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES

> "The c0-* options for rate-limiting have been removed.  Instead, a backoff
>     approach is used."

So you should remove them from your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:
`make install` doesn't tell your package manager about installed files so 
I think there's a problem/conflict with your distribution package and your build :

1) check tmux package in your package-manger or synaptic & delete it & go to tmux build folder run `make uninstall` & install it again .

Or

2) for a better building process , build deb/rpm/.. packages is the best as it'll tell you package manager so replace the old version with a tool like checkinstall that will be easy,

instead of :

```
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

do :

```
./configure && make
sudo checkinstall
```

in my case ubuntu 14.04 that make my day happy,(I don't remember if I configureed some options, whatever)

Comment: Thanks, recompiling fixed my issue too. Although for me it was caused by upgrading to El Capitan (OS X).

Comment: Nevermind the problem was actually that it's been removed.